# Sub select time periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, subquery

I have 2 columns for timestamp:

1. `START` (eg. 2015-11-18 10:00)
2. `STOP` (eg. 2015-11-18 22:00)

I also have by calendar (events, busy), which has 3 columns:

1. `What` (varchar(50)) (eg. Coffee break)
2. `START` (timestamp) (eg. 2015-11-18 10:55)
3. `STOP`  (timestamp) (eg. 2015-11-18 11:55)

How can I return all free time periods as single timestamps
ie.

```
free time1: 2015-11-18 10:00 - 2015-11-18 10:55  
free time2: 2015-11-18 11:55 - 2015-11-18 22:00
```

as a single postgresql query?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want `not exists`:

```
select ts.*
from timestamps ts
where not exists (select 1
                  from calendar c
                  where ts.start <= c.end and
                        ts.end >= c.start
                 );
```

You might need to adjust the inequalities to be strict inequalities, depending on how you define overlapping.  Note:  you can also use the `overlaps` keyword, but I never remember whether it includes the end points or not, which is why I write the logic out explicitly.

Comment: but if i have more taks a day? how to find all gaps?

Comment: @blackmoon . . . This should find all gaps.